# Is a call to free() in the forked process causing a copy-on-write?

Tags: c, fork, free, copy-on-write

From [man fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html):

```
   Under Linux, fork() is implemented using copy-on-write pages, so
   the only penalty that it incurs is the time and memory required
   to duplicate the parent's page tables, and to create a unique
   task structure for the child.
```

Therefore, in an example like this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *data = malloc(100);

    snprintf(data, 100, "%s", "Hello world!");

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // start of child process
        printf("I'm the child\n");
        // Do the child stuff ...
        puts(data);
    }
    else
    {
        // start of parent process
        printf("I'm the parent\n");
        // Do the parent stuff ...
        puts(data);
        // Wait for child process
        if (wait(NULL) == -1)
        {
            perror("wait");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        free(data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

for what I understand, if a resource is duplicated but not modified, it is not necessary to create a new resource and the memory reserved with `malloc` is not copied/duplicated in the forked process and instead we get a pointer to the memory reserved in the parent process.

On the other hand, if the resource is not freed in the child process, we get a memory leak:

```
==13024== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13024==     in use at exit: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==13024==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,124 bytes allocated
==13024== 
==13024== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13024==    definitely lost: 100 bytes in 1 blocks
==13024==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13024==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13024==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13024==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13024== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13024== 
==13024== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==13024== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==13023== 
==13023== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13023==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13023==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,124 bytes allocated
==13023== 
==13023== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13023== 
==13023== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==13023== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Which indicates that you should call `free()` from the forked process.

```
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // start of child process
        printf("I'm the child\n");
        // Do the child stuff ...
        puts(data);
        free(data);
    }
```

Is a call to `free()` in the forked process causing a copy-on-write?

Comment: `free` will modify some structure in the heap, so yes a copy-on-write will occur for this portion of memory. But the main thing in your program is that it is `puts` that will be the cause of copy-on-write for the allocated memory...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès thanks for the comment. Can you elaborate on this: _is puts that will be the cause of copy-on-write_?  As far as I know `puts` doesn't alter the memory block.

Comment: Right puts only read, it's a mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it certainly does.

Memory copy-on-write (CoW) happens on a different layer than `malloc()`/`free()`.

When a process is forked, the child process has all its mapped pages marked as shared from the parent (and thus read-only). When the child modifies a shared page, it triggers a page fault and only then does the operating system copy the data to another area in the physical RAM (and change the mapping for the process).

`malloc()` and `free()` do *not* allocate physical RAM. They are *memory* management functions, with *memory* defined as "the (virtual) address space of a process". Thus, these C library functions keep track of an internal state of allocated memory chunks, and `malloc()` and `free()` only modifies these libc-internal data structures (with an exception of requesting more address space from the OS when `malloc()`-ing). Physical RAM allocation only happens at page fault, most commonly when a process accesses newly assigned memory for the first time.

In this respect, yes. As `free()` must modify memory to mark a region as freed, it will write to the relevant region, and at the lower level cause a remapping (i.e. CoW).